Spring Security 6 configuration with custom form login
I am building a Spring Boot application with an endpoint "/admin" which requires authentication in order to be accessed; all other endpoints should be accessible without authentication. Furthermore, the authenticated user should have the "ADMIN" authority if accessing any of the pages on the "/admin" endpoint. I use a custom login page as well as a custom failure handler and a custom success handler upon logging in. I need to keep in mind that other secure endpoints with different security configurations could be added in the future (example: an api endpoint with JWT authentication & authorization).
When I attempt to login, I get the following error:
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' is not supported]
I thought the login processing was performed automatically by Spring Security, but perhaps I am missing something?
Here is the security configuration:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private LoginSuccessHandler loginSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private LoginFailureHandler loginFailureHandler;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new MyUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());

        return new ProviderManager(provider);
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain adminFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .securityMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/admin/**"))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .anyRequest()
                        .hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                )
                .formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .failureHandler(loginFailureHandler)
                        .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler)
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .logout(logout -> logout
                        .logoutUrl("/logout")
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                );

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(def -> def
                        .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**"))
                        .permitAll()
                );

        return http.build();
    }

Here is the login form:
<form class="login-card-form" th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
            <div class="form-item">
                <input type="email" name="username" placeholder="Enter email" required autofocus />
            </div>
            <div class="form-item">
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password" required />
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="role" value="ADMIN">
            <button type="submit">Log In</button>
        </form>

Controller form method:
@GetMapping(value="login")
    public ModelAndView displayLoginPage() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("login");

        return modelAndView;
    }

LoginFailureHandler, where the login failure logic is implemented:
@Component
public class LoginFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private LoginAttemptService loginAttemptService;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        String role = request.getParameter("role");

        if (user != null) {
            if (user.isEnabled()) {
                if (user.getFailedAttempts() < LoginAttemptService.MAX_FAILED_ATTEMPTS - 1) {
                    loginAttemptService.increaseFailedAttempts(user);
                } else {
                    loginAttemptService.lock(user);
                    exception = new LockedException("Your account has been locked due to " + LoginAttemptService.MAX_FAILED_ATTEMPTS + " failed attempts." + " It will be unlocked after 24 hours.");
                }
            } else if (!user.isEnabled()) {
                if (loginAttemptService.unlockWhenTimeExpired(user)) {
                    exception = new LockedException("Your account has been unlocked. Please try to login again.");
                }
            }
        }

        if (role.equals("USER")){
            super.setDefaultFailureUrl("/login?errorUser");
        } else {
            super.setDefaultFailureUrl("/login?errorAdmin");
        }
        super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
    }
 }

LoginSuccessHandler, where the login success logic is implemented:
@Component
public class LoginSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    @Autowired
    private LoginAttemptService loginAttemptService;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
        MyUserDetails userDetails = (MyUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
        User user = userDetails.getUser();
        if (user.getFailedAttempts() > 0) {
            loginAttemptService.resetFailedAttempts(user.getEmail());
        }

        String redirectURL = request.getContextPath();
        String submittedRole = request.getParameter("role");

        if (submittedRole.equals("ADMIN") && userDetails.hasRole("ADMIN")) {
            redirectURL = "/admin/home";
        } else if (submittedRole.equals("ADMIN") && !userDetails.hasRole("ADMIN")) {
            redirectURL = "/login?wrongrole";
        }

        if (!user.isEnabled() && user.getLockTime() != null) {
            redirectURL = "/login?disabled";
        }

        response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
    }
}

I have checked out different solutions on StackOverflow, including this one which seemed pretty close to my case:
Method 'POST' is not supported in Spring Security 6
as well as the Spring Java configuration for multiple configurations doc:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/servlet/configuration/java.html#_multiple_httpsecurity
However I haven't managed to make my login part work properly.

First you can do is to remove authenticationManager() function it is not needed second enable debug logs and include then in full
